# Dialog Box not Closing After pressing X Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've one scenario. I'm opening a dialog box, but my parent window refreshes after every one minute. Let's say my dialog box is opened for 5 minutes, then I have to press 5 times the `X` button to close that dialog box. Any idea why this is happening ?

For opening the dialog box I used the following code:

```
var dialogOptions = { overflow: 'scroll',height: 100,width: 500,show: true, hide: true, modal: true};
$('#act_summary').dialog(dialogOptions);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would the parent window refresh every minute? Sounds horrible!

Comment: I don't understand: how can you keep a dialog opened for 5 minuties if the page refresh at any minute?

Comment: Maybe you are not closing your dialog 5 times but closing 5 dialogs? :)

Comment: A little correction..Only a part (an applet containing records) of the parent page refreshes every minute, not the whole page..And the button which opens the dialog box is in the same applet which refreshes.

Comment: Check that `$('#act_summary')` exists before creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if that dialog exists first:

```
if (!$('#act_summary').length > 0){
  $('#act_summary').dialog(dialogOptions);
}
```

If you don't you'll just keep creating new ones. This is why it appears that you have to click it 5 times. You're actually closing 5 instances of the dialog.

Comment: If Im not opening dialogbox @ strt but lets say the applet refreshed 3 times and then I open the dbox.In that case also I have to press X button 3 times. Why is this happening?
This is the total code:
myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.setAttribute('id','act_summary');
myDiv.setAttribute('title','Activity Summary');
var jqmyDiv = $(myDiv);
myDiv.innerHTML = htmlstr;
jqmyDiv.appendTo('#pager_s_1_l_left');
var dialogOptions = { overflow: 'scroll',height: 100,width: 500,show: true, hide: true, modal: true};
if (!$('#act_summary').length > 0){
$('#act_summary').dialog(dialogOptions);
}

Comment: You're still creating the `<div>` before checking it exists `myDiv = document.createElement('div');` You're also mixing `javascript` and `jquery`. You need to clean you're code up.

Comment: @Chiranjit Are you creating the `div` many times? If yes, then I will tell you some secret: **ID must be unique!!!**

Comment: @Palvo I am cerating that div many times on button click, but the thing is if the applet in the parent page refreshes I have to click cross button as many times as the applet refreshes.Just I saw that dialogbox is created that many times even if I opened the dialogbox after 5 times applet refresh I have to close 5 dbox.Why is that happening?

Comment: @Chiranjit I can't tell you because you didn't provide your code.

Comment: Please can you not discuss this on my answer. Thank you